# Knn imputation using the caret package is inducing negative values in the data

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-science, knn, imputation

[image]I have been trying to do KNN imputation for some missing values in R but it has been inducing negative values in columns where there shouldn't be any negative values at all like age.(Age does have missing values but I don't want it to get imputed by negative values).

Here is my code:

```
#KNN Imputation:
preProcess_missingdata_model <- preProcess(train, method='knnImpute')
preProcess_missingdata_model

# Use the imputation model to predict the values of missing data points
library(RANN)  # required for knnImpute
train <- predict(preProcess_missingdata_model, newdata = train)
```

What should I do to overcome these negative values being induced?
Any suggestions would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Post a snippet of your input `train`, and your output, showing where the negative values occur.

Comment: I have been working on the Titanic Dataset from Kaggle. I have posted a picture of my output. As you can see there are negative value induced in the Passenger ID and the Age column which were both integer variables and the age column had the missing data

Comment: Well did you scale `age` to (-2,+2) or something before imputing? or what? Age is not uniformly distributed, so that might not be a great way, `log1p()` then scaling might be better. See e.g. [Stats.SE: Should data be normalized before or after imputation of missing data?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/214728/should-data-be-normalized-before-or-after-imputation-of-missing-data)

Comment: **You should never use PassengerID in prediction**, it's only an id-variable. Exclude it.

Answer (score 0):

You are able to expressly tell `preProcessing` which columns you would like to impute. This can be done as follows:

`preProcess_missingdata_model <- preProcess(train[,c('Embarked', 'Sex')], method='knnImpute')`

You can even specify the specific rows you would like to impute by including a list before the comma.

Answer (score 0):

KnnImpute of Caret package automatically center and scale your data, so negative values are normal (in fact, if you watch the result of the function you can see it).